# I'm not able to get informations from TVmaze API

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to get all the urls of the shows that are listed https://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2021-03-24 here but im getting just a blank page and I don't have any ideea why.

```
function request($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}


$api_url = 'https://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2021-03-23';

$data = request($api_url);

$final_data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($final_data); $x++) 
{
    echo $finaldata[$x]['show']['url']."\n";
}
```

Comment: Debug your cURL : [`curl_error($ch)`](https://php.net/curl_error) after `curl_exec($ch)` if `$data === false`.

Comment: Nope, still blank, also if I print_r $final_data it works fine but im not able to get the specific info that I need.

Comment: `$data = curl_exec($ch); if($data === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); } curl_close($ch);`.

Comment: Yea, I did it, but the function request works corectly. The problem is somewhere in the for statement. I'm not able to get the infos that i want, even if i manually put 0/1/2/3     echo $finaldata[0]['show']['url']."\n"; here

Comment: What is the result content of `$data` or `$final_data` ? (edit your question to add a small piece of it). `$final_data` should be a Countable.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GxCpd6hvfq/ this is the json that i get from $final_data
The $final_data can be counted, since i see 67rows in view source, but they are because of the \n and not showing any URL.